# CSV file parser with some checks for header fields and duplicate rows

Tags: python, validation, csv

I have built a sample Parser class on top of the csv module for basic checks that we normally need as the first step of pre-processing. I would love a bit of feedback on the code and any areas that I can improve upon in the code to make it more efficient.

```
import csv

from exceptions import CompulsoryHeaderCheckFailed


class CsvParser:
    def __init__(self, file: str, compulsory_headers: list):
        self.file = file
        self.compulsory_headers = compulsory_headers
        self.duplicate_rows = []
        self.good_rows = []
        self.bad_rows = []
        self.log = []

    def diff_headers(self):
        reader = csv.reader(open(self.file))
        header = next(reader)
        return set(self.compulsory_headers) - set(header)

    def passes_compulsory_header_check(self):
        return True if not self.diff_headers() else False

    def is_bad_row(self, line_num: int, curr_row: tuple):
        if not all(curr_row):
            self.bad_rows.append(({"line_num": line_num, "row": list(curr_row)}))
            return True
        return False

    def _append_log(self, line_num: int):
        self.log.append({"total_num_of_rows_processed": line_num,
                         "good_rows": self.good_rows,
                         "bad_rows": self.bad_rows,
                         "duplicate_rows": self.duplicate_rows,
                         })

    @property
    def row(self):
        rows = csv.reader(open(self.file))
        next(rows)
        for _row in rows:
            yield _row

    @property
    def col(self):
        rows = csv.reader(open(self.file))
        for row in rows:
            return row

    def _parse_rows(self):
        _rows = set()
        rows = csv.reader(open(self.file))
        next(rows)
        line_num = 1
        _rows = set()
        for row in rows:
            line_num += 1
            row = tuple(row)
            if not (self.is_bad_row(line_num, row)):
                if row not in _rows:
                    _rows.add(row)
                    self.good_rows.append({"line_num": line_num, "row": list(row)})
                else:
                    self.duplicate_rows.append({"line_num": line_num,
                                                "row": list(row)
                                                })
        self._append_log(line_num)

    def process_csv(self, skip_header_check=False):
        if skip_header_check:
            self._parse_rows()
        else:
            if self.passes_compulsory_header_check():
                self._parse_rows()
            else:
                raise CompulsoryHeaderCheckFailed("compulsory headers missing from csv")


csv_parser = CsvParser("hello.csv", compulsory_headers=["id", "student", "marks", ])
print(csv_parser.process_csv())
print(csv_parser.good_rows)
print(csv_parser.bad_rows)
print(csv_parser.duplicate_rows)
print(csv_parser.log)
```

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 4 → 2.

Comment: @200_success you've got answering, editing, and modding on the same Q&A.  There should be an achievement/badge for this.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Interface

The interface for this class is awkward, and it's not clear how it's meant to be used.

- Is `diff_headers()` supposed to be part of the interface?  How about `passes_compulsory_header_check()`?  Maybe they should be considered private, to be used internally by `process_csv()`?
- The `is_bad_row(line_num, curr_row)` method definitely seems like it's supposed to be a private method for internal use: how else would a caller come up with a line number and a tuple of data to pass to it?  The worst aspect of this method is that even though its name suggests that it just performs a test, it actually has a side-effect of maybe appending something to `self.bad_rows`.
- The `_append_log()` method appends to `self.log`, but considering that the "log" should contain a single item that is a summary of the outcome of parsing the entire file, why is `self.log` a list at all?  For that matter, why should there be a "log" at all?  As your sample usage shows, you can get that information from `csv_parser.good_rows`, `csv_parser.bad_rows`, etc. — all that's missing is the line count, and you could modify the class so that the line count could be queried likewise.
- It's highly unorthodox that `row()` is a property that is also a generator — especially since the name of the method is singular rather than plural.
- I don't know what the `col()` method is for, but it looks entirely wrong, and you never call it.
- The `process_csv()` method looks somewhat reasonable.  But why is there a `skip_header_check` option?  Couldn't the caller also effectively skip the header check by specifying no compulsory headers?  It seems simpler and more Pythonic to offer just one way to accomplish a particular goal.

### Design suggestion

If I had to write this class, I'd design it so that it works pretty much as a drop-in replacement for the `csv.DictReader` class, such that iterating over the reader streams the "good" rows, but keeps track of the bad and duplicate rows that it encounters.

### Implementation

In several places, you write `reader = csv.reader(open(self.file))`, often followed by `next(rows)` to skip the header row.  It would be better to design the class so that it opens the file just once, and makes one linear pass through its contents.  Also, a `csv.DictReader` would be a better way to handle the header row.

What exactly constitutes a "bad" row?  A row that has an empty field?  Your criterion is `all(curr_row)`, but you should be aware that if the row has fewer fields than expected, that will be considered acceptable.

In `_parse_rows()`, you initialized `_rows = set()` twice.  To write a `for` loop that maintains a count while iterating, the Python idiom is to use `enumerate()`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will refactor the code with the above suggestions and do an update here with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback from 200_success, here is revised version of the code

```
import csv

from exceptions import CompulsoryHeaderCheckFailed


class CsvParser:
    def __init__(self, file: str, compulsory_headers: list):
        self.file = file
        self.compulsory_headers = compulsory_headers
        self.duplicate_rows = []
        self.good_rows = []
        self.bad_rows = []
        self.reader = None
        self.total_lines_processed = None
        self.num_of_columns = None

    def _reader(self):
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(open(self.file))

    def _diff_headers(self):
        reader = self.reader
        header = reader.fieldnames
        self.num_of_columns = len(header)
        return set(self.compulsory_headers) - set(header)

    def _passes_compulsory_header_check(self):
        return True if not self._diff_headers() else False

    def _parse_rows(self):
        rows = self.reader
        _rows = set()
        line_num = None
        for line_num, row in enumerate(rows, start=1):
            row = tuple(row.values())
            if all(row) and self.num_of_columns == len(row):
                if row not in _rows:
                    _rows.add(row)
                    self.good_rows.append({"line_num": line_num, "row": list(row)})
                else:
                    self.duplicate_rows.append({"line_num": line_num,
                                                "row": list(row)
                                                })
            else:
                self.bad_rows.append(({"line_num": line_num, "row": list(row)}))
        self.total_lines_processed = line_num

    def process_csv(self):
        self._reader()
        if not self.compulsory_headers:
            self._parse_rows()
        else:
            if self._passes_compulsory_header_check():
                self._parse_rows()
            else:
                raise CompulsoryHeaderCheckFailed("compulsory headers missing from csv")


csv_parser = CsvParser("hello.csv", compulsory_headers=["id", "student", "marks", ])
csv_parser.process_csv()
print(csv_parser.good_rows)
print(csv_parser.bad_rows)
print(csv_parser.duplicate_rows)
print(csv_parser.total_lines_processed)
```

Comment: @200_success - Thank you for the advise. I made few edits in the code. Can you please advise on the revised version ?

Comment: Thanks for posting this code.  It's a good idea to summarise which changes you made, and why - a self-answer ought to review the code, just like any other answer.

Comment: If you have additional or improved code for review, you should post it as a  [new question](/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: The `if not self.compulsory_headers: …` special case is a bad idea. Do you see how that codepath can cause a crash? If I recall correctly, `DictReader` already enforces that each row contains the expected number of fields.

Comment: @200_success - Yeah you are right. I will make the edit